# Running c binary as android service

Tags: android, c, service, binary

I know how to run c program on android (ndk) but I have NO IDEA how to run a c binary as android service. I want to run java application which will be connecting to the c binary. Is there any chance to do this?

Thanks for you help.

Comment: [This?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868309/how-can-i-run-c-binary-executable-file-in-android-from-android-shell)

Comment: You need to create .so file and use it as library file. Hope link provided by memphis or [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21901061/how-to-use-so-file-to-create-an-apk-file-in-android-application-for-my-custom) help you.